# Why is $\frac{\log 8}{\log 3} = \frac{\ln8}{\ln3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need help clarifying why:

$$\frac{\log 8}{\log 3} = \frac{\ln8}{\ln3}$$

To my understanding $\ln$ implies $\log$ base e and $\log 8$ implies $\log$ base $10$ of $8$. Kind of confused how that is equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: Use logarithm Laws

Comment: This link will help you <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107574/from-natural-log-to-log-base-10>

Comment: @User good thread, thank bud

Answer (score 3):

use that $$\frac{\log_{c}{b}}{\log_{c}{a}}=\log_{a}{b}$$